# rlwrap: mysql autocompletion not working

Tags: command-line, mysql, line-editor

Normally, autocompletion works fine in mysql command-line client (`mysql-client-5.5`). I have a table called `booking`. When I type the letter `b` and pres `TAB` the name of my table gets autocompleted:

```
SELECT * FROM b<TAB>
```

However, when I use `rlwrap` (`alias mysql='/usr/bin/rlwrap -s 99999 -a -pRED /usr/bin/mysql'`), autocompletion stops working.

It looks as if `rlwrap` is interfering with the autocompletion feature.

I am using Debian Wheezy.

**UPDATE 1**:

When I start my command with `strace`, ie:

```
strace /usr/bin/rlwrap -s 99999 -a -pRED /usr/bin/mysql --auto-rehash
```

I see following error

```
access("/usr/share/rlwrap/completions/mysql", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

could it be, that rlwrap needs some file with mysql completions?

**UPDATE 2**

OK, I have created the file `/usr/share/rlwrap/completions/mysql` and put 3 sample lines there:

```
select
from
where
```

Now when I start `mysql` and type `sele<TAB>`, the tab actually completes the word `select`. That is progress, but that does not solve the whole problem. I mainly need autocompletion to help me complete obscure table names which I don't (want to) remember. But I cannot edit the autocomplete file every time I change/add/rename a table.

Is it not possible to tell `rlwrap` to use the same autocomplete file as `mysql` does? (I presume `mysql` must use some such file)

**UPDATE 3**:

following are the other errors from `strace`

```
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/martin/.terminfo", 0x7fff27ee6a70) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/terminfo/x/xterm-256color", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/martin/.mysql_completions", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/share/rlwrap/completions/mysql", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/martin/.inputrc", 0x7fff27ee7710) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Why are you using rlwrap? `mysql` already used readline.

Comment: Not my `mysql` (I am using Debian Wheezy)

Comment: A long shot and not my field, but you may find value in the idea of using a dictionary file for auto-completion, like [this](http://www.oraclealchemist.com/news/add-history-and-tab-completion-to-sqlplus/) or [here](http://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2013/07/06/simple-pleasures-rlwrap-and-sqlplus-command-line-editing-on-linux/) and that last link goes to [this](http://www.linuxification.at/rlwrap_ext.html.en) which contains already made dictionary files for different setups. Then you would use `rlwrap -if dictfile sqlplus whatever` -i to ignore case and -f to use the file dictfile.

Comment: That's the first good lead we've had! I believe that's suppose to be a directory too, probably w/ some config files for rlwrap or mysql. http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/b/weblog/archive/2013/07/06/simple-pleasures-rlwrap-and-sql-plus-command-line-editing-on-linux.aspx

Comment: @slm - please see my update again

Comment: Is there anymore errors with another `strace` and the addition of the file?

Comment: I guess, the question now is, where does `mysql` normally get its auto completion information from?

Answer (score 2):

Edit `my.cnf`:

```
[mysql]
auto-rehash
```

If that doesn't work, add it to `debian.cnf` instead.

Even you can do it:

```
mysql> \#
```

Comment: neither has any effect - auto-completion still does not work

Comment: It sounds like you have another problem; it should work with the above change.

Answer (score 2):

This will enable completion on plain mysql server:

```
mysql --auto-rehash
```

For `rlwrap`, check if you have `RLWRAP_HOME` set. See [here](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/rlwrap.html#ENVIRONMENT) for more info. The page also [reports](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/rlwrap.html#BUGS%20and%20LIMITATIONS) possible race conditions if your system is too busy.

Answer (score 0):

I found this bit on a FreeBSD forum but it should work for you in your case as well. The forum thread was titled: [Why no autocomplete in mysql with bash?](https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?&t=34754).

The solutions mentioned in that thread are as follows.

#### Option #1 - via mysql client

```
$ mysql --auto-rehash -p
```

This is directly out of the `mysql` man page.

```
--auto-rehash

Enable automatic rehashing. This option is on by default, which enables 
database, table, and column name completion. Use --disable-auto-rehash to 
disable rehashing. That causes mysql to start faster, but you must issue the 
rehash command if you want to use name completion.

To complete a name, enter the first part and press Tab. If the name is 
unambiguous, mysql completes it. Otherwise, you can press Tab again to see 
the possible names that begin with what you have typed so far. Completion 
does not occur if there is no default database.
```

#### Option #2 - via the server

You can also fix this on the server end by commenting out that same feature line in the server's `/etc/my.cnf` file. It depends on where your `my.cnf` file came from. MySQL provides several out of the box sample `.cnf` files.

#### Example

This is on my CentOS system buy your Debian system likely has these as well.

```
$ rpm -ql mysql-server |grep cnf 
/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0.95/my-huge.cnf
/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0.95/my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf
/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0.95/my-large.cnf
/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0.95/my-medium.cnf
/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0.95/my-small.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-huge.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-large.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-medium.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-small.cnf
```

If one of these files is the basis for your `/etc/my.cnf` file then you may have this line enabled within it. For example these files have it enabled:

```
$ grep rehash /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0.95/*
/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0.95/my-huge.cnf:no-auto-rehash
/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0.95/my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf:no-auto-rehash
/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0.95/my-large.cnf:no-auto-rehash
/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0.95/my-medium.cnf:no-auto-rehash
/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0.95/my-small.cnf:no-auto-rehash
```

So you'll want to comment this line out if you have it enabled in your `/etc/my.cnf` file, like so:

```
#no-auto-rehash
```

#### Your alias

Given the method you're employing to call the mysql client using `rlwrap` you could append the `--auto-hash -p` switches to it like so:

```
$ alias mysql='/usr/bin/rlwrap -s 99999 -a -pRED /usr/bin/mysql --auto-rehash -p'
```

Comment: none of these tricks work. Moreover, I presume you meant `--auto-rehash -p` not `--auto-hash -p` in the alias command. But why the `-p`? (The password to use when connecting to the server)

Comment: @MartinVegter - yup, I fixed the typo. I always have to provide a password to connect to my MySQL servers.

Comment: please see my update